# Como consultar un periodo de fechas en un stored procedure de SQL SERVER dentro de strings

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Deseo consultar por periodo de fechas, en lugar de GETDATE quiero poner una fecha 2022-12-29T08:00:00 pero como deberian ir dentro de comillas simples no me las reconoce

```
Set @SQL = 'Declare @FechaFinal DateTime, @Fechainicial datetime ' 

Set @SQL = @SQL + 'SET @FechaInicial = GETDATE()-7 ' 

Set @SQL = @SQL + 'SET @FechaFinal = DATEADD(HH,-1,@FechaInicial+7) '
```

Y utilizar la variable aqui

```
set @SQL = 'Select t.* Into #PasoTran From [' + @IPServidor + '].bd.dbo.Transacciones as t Where t.FechaHora >= @FechaInicial and t.FechaHora <= @FechaFinal '
```

al final ejecuto

```
Exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Prueba con `'SET @FechaInicial = ''2020-12-29'''`, nota que estamos escapando la comillas simples con dos comillas simples

Comment: Gracias, añadi este formato ''2021-02-01T00:00:00'' ya que si solo pongo la fecha el mes es el ultimo par (01 Enero) y lo estaba confundiendo con el dia

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, lo que debes hacer es parametrizar tu consulta en vez de ingresar literales que pueden dejar tu código abierto a inyección de SQL.

En este caso, hay la posibilidad de mostrar las diversas formas de evitar la inyección de SQL. La primera es parametrizar la consulta y ejecutar el código usando `sp_executesql`. La segunda es validando los nombres de los objetos que concatenas en la consulta mediante las vistas del sistema y la función `QUOTENAME()`. Otro detalle es que el hecho de que el código sea dinámico, no tiene por que evitar ser formateado.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @IPServidor nvarchar(20) = '50.28.39.254';

Declare @FechaFinal DateTime, 
        @Fechainicial datetime;

SET @FechaInicial = GETDATE()-7;
SET @FechaFinal = DATEADD(HH,-1,@FechaInicial+7);

--Se utiliza SELECT para validar que el servidor esté dado de alta
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT t.* ' + CHAR(13)
            + N'INTO   #PasoTran ' + CHAR(13)
            -- Se utiliza QUOTENAME para manipular nombres con caracteres especiales
            + N'FROM   ' + QUOTENAME( name) + '.bd.dbo.Transacciones as t ' + CHAR(13)
            + N'WHERE  t.FechaHora >= @FechaInicial ' + CHAR(13)
            + N'AND    t.FechaHora <= @FechaFinal '
FROM sys.servers
WHERE name = @IPServidor

--Descomentar para validar la cadena
--PRINT @SQL

--Ejecutar la consulta
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FechaFinal DateTime, @Fechainicial datetime', @FechaFinal, @Fechainicial;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estare probando, esto